# Why .vimrc reports error when adding recorded macro?

Tags: vimrc, macro

I've created a macro to add a piece of code.
The macro runs fine.
But when added to .vimrc, it reports error.
(The macro becomes weird when paste here.)
    `let @p='iprocess (clk, resetn)`
    `€kbbegin`
    `if (resetn = '0') then`

```
€kbelse€kbif (clk'event and clk = '1') then

€kbend if;
€kbend if;
€ku€@7€kb€kb€kb€kd€kuprocess;q€kb'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your problem comes from the way you entered the special characters. You can try to use this command: `call setreg('p', "iprocess (clk, resetn)^M€kbbegin^Mif (resetn = '0') then^M")` note that the `^M` should be added by pressing `<C-v><CR>` in insert mode to enter the keycode of the return key.

Comment: Great! Calll setreg is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you initialize has two flaws:

First, it is usually better to use `setreg()` to set the value of a register, it is more robust than `let @X =` and allows you to choose the type of the register (characterwise, linewise, blockwise)

Second, your string contains the keycode of some key (e.g. `^M` for `<CR>`). I guess that you recorded your macro and tried to get what you recorded and that's what caused the problem. In your vimrc you need to write the following:

```
call setreg('p',  "iprocess (clk, resetn)^M€kbbegin^Mif (resetn = '0') then^M")
```

where `^M` is not entered manually but is entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> this allows you to write the keycode of the key which `setreg()` can then interpret properly. Note that you should do that with the others special keys like `<Esc>` for example.

**Edit** As mentioned by @Rich in the comments using `\<CR>` inside a double quoted string is arguably more robust than `<C-v><CR>`.

See:

- [`:h setreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setreg%28%29)
- [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V)

Comment: Yes, macro content was pasted by <C-r><C-r>a. Normally I'll not manually edit the register content. It's great to know the details about ^M. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that, inside a double-quote string, `\<CR>` can be used instead of `CTRL-V Enter`? It's arguably more robust, especially when copy/pasting answers from SE sites!